# Packaging a batch for a web-app

Tags: spring, maven, spring-batch

Until now I was working on a java web-app that uses spring like application container and maven like build tool. Now I'm designing a new layer batch that should extract some time-consuming method from web app to batch layer. The problem is that until when the batch layer and the scheduler are not ready, I have to allow  to invoke these rewritten procedure from the web-app.

My idea is that to begin to write some batch in a separate project (with jar packaging) and add it like dependency of my web-app.

For example the pom of my web-app will be:

```
.....
<dependencies>

    ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myCompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyBatchProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
.....
```

My batch project will contain Job1,Job2 ecc and from my web app I will have:

```
    @Controller
    public class JobLauncherController {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @RequestMapping("/jobLauncher.html")
    public void handle() throws Exception{
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }
}
```

Can you give me some suggestion about this? Could be this a good strategy for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing makes sense to me.  In fact, we've already done that for you with Spring Batch Admin (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/).  Spring Batch Admin is a framework for launching jobs via a web application.  It currently provides a UI as well as a collection of REST endpoints that you can call to launch your jobs. It's also embeddable into an existing web application.